# glInvalidateFramebuffer and data usability time

Tags: opengl-es, egl

I render to a number of FBOs with the intent of binding them as a texture in a later drawcall. As far as I know, I should call glInvalidateFramebuffer if I do not intend the data in the FBOs to be relevant in the next frame anymore.

My question is, assuming I call glInvalidateFramebuffer right before the glBindFramebuffer that unbinds the current FBO as a render target, how long will I be able to use that FBO as input texture for render calls until the data becomes unusable? Until the unbinding glBindFramebuffer? Until the next drawcall that uses the texture? Until eglSwapBuffers?

Answer (score 3):

The pixels become invalidated immediately, as far as any subsequent commands are concerned. Remember: while OpenGL can execute asynchronously, it is [*defined* to execute synchronously](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Memory_Model) (with a few exceptions). So any subsequent commands will execute as if prior commands have completed.

Comment: The tutorials tell me that I should call glInvalidateFramebuffer before I unbind the FBO because thats when the expensive stuff is done. However, I still need the FBO as input for a drawcall. Is glInvalidateFramebuffer useful for me at all?

Comment: @Desperado17 Which tutorial? Also note, that it could be that the unbinding does some work. But it is not guaranteed by the standard, thus such hints will usually only be true for a single vendor/os/driver.

Comment: You want to invalidate the transient attachments before you unbind. E.g. if you have color, depth and stencil, but only need to persist color then you do want to invalidate depth and stencil. For most mobile GPUs, which have some form of local tightly coupled tile memory, this avoids the need to write depth and stencil back to main memory. Obviously don't invalidate anything you actually need to keep ...

Comment: http://graphics1600.rssing.com/chan-25333833/all_p4.html      Section "When to call glInvalidateFramebuffer?"

Comment: @solidpixel: So you mean if I render to an FBO that I plan to use as a texture (where I only need the color component) then I can discard depth and stencil after rendering to said FBO before I unbind it as render target and save cpu time, right?

Comment: Yes, but the saving is GPU time (sometimes, if writeback is the bottleneck) and memory bandwidth (always) because you never write the depth and stencil data back to main memory.